# How can I force Google to re-crawl a link?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing

Google Webmaster Tools is showing thousands of links from a North Korean travel agency, but when I go to the link, they don't exist! How can I force Google to re-index that link so it drops off my list of incoming links?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have to wait for Google to re-crawl the page on whatever schedule it has determined they will crawl that page. It could be every hour, it could be once a month. Unfortunately you have no control over that.

Comment: It's been at least a month since I've noticed the links are missing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the links which do not exists anymore, add a 301 redirection.

and [Ask Google to re-crawl your URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?rd=1) from your [Webmasters account](https://www.google.com/webmasters/).

Comment: No, the links on the foreign site do not exist on the foreign site. The foreign page no longer links to me (or maybe never did).

Comment: ohh.. you can't control websites which are not under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to possibly speed up the re-crawl of a link - just link to the page from a highly trafficked site so Google re-crawls it!

http://www.hiswebmarketing.com/tell-link-disavowed/

> #### Can you force Google to revisit an old page?
>
> Many people have asked me if it is possible to speed up the disavow process.  John Mueller was asked in a hangout a while back if you could use the submit to Google feature to get Google to revisit a url but John said that that wouldn’t work.  Another possible solution is to actually build links to the pages that you want Google to revisit.  The idea is that as Google spidered your site with these links on them then they would end up spidering the spammy pages as they follow the links.  To do this you’d likely want to set up the links on sites that you don’t care about and that aren’t connected with your own sites.  There is no specific penalty that I am aware of that Google would give for this type of action but my gut tells me that it’s something that might be frowned upon by the webspam team.  Still…I’m in the process of doing some experiments.  I’ll let you know if they work out.